# Performance difference when inverting a binary tree

Tags: java

Now I have two solution. But I can't figure out why the first solution is faster than the second solution.

First solution

```
public class Solution {
  public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null)
            return root;

        if(root.left==null && root.right==null)
            return root;

        TreeNode temp = null;
        root.left = invertTree(root.left);
        root.right =invertTree(root.right);
        temp = root.left;
        root.left = root.right;
        root.right = temp;
        return root;
    }
}
```

Second solution

```
public class Solution {
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null)
            return null;

        if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
            return root;

        TreeNode temp = root.left;
        root.left = root.right;
        root.right = temp;
        invertTree(root.left);
        invertTree(root.right);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting question!  Can you provide the actual time measurements and also post your methodology for measuring the performance?

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with the arrangement of the invertTree. Probably assigning it is faster for the compiler then having to update an existing reference.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr: No, that has ***nothing*** do to with this.  Not this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be worth seeing real numbers. But if we talk about quite big trees, it could be because of caching:
In the first solution you read root.left and root.right, then do the inversion and at the end you again manipulate root.left and root.right.
In the second solution you swap root.left and root.right and then immediately do the inversion. So you avoid at least one cache-miss for each node. Actually even the instruction code may be one instruction shorter as it may reuse already read variable.